# Why is injectiveness needed to show that a bounded linear operator is a closed map?

Tags: banach-spaces, functional-equations, closed-map

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach. I'm trying to show that a bounded linear map $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed map, that is $A\subset X$ is closed $\implies T(A)\subset Y$ is closed, if $T$ is injective and $T(X)$ is closed.
My question is: Is the injectiveness of $T$ necessary?$$ $$ If we consider a sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset A$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{x_n}=x$ for some $x\in X$, then $x\in A$, because $A$ is closed. So by continuity of $T$ we get $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{Tx_n}=Tx\in T(A)$. I don't see where it is necessary to assume that $T$ is injective.

Comment: Your attempt is not valid, as it only considers images of convergent sequences. You should be considering some arbitrary $y_n \in T(A)$ converging to $y \in Y$. Yes, we can then say there exists a sequence $x_n \in A$ such that $y_n = Tx_n$, but there's no guarantee that $x_n$ is convergent.

Comment: So for $y_n=Tx_n$ and $y=Tx$ we have $\Vert T(x_n-x)\Vert\rightarrow 0$. Since T is injective (i.e $Tx=0\implies x=0$) we have $\Vert x_n-x\Vert\rightarrow 0$. So the convergence of $x_n$ follows from the injectiveness of $T$. Is that right?

Comment: What is $x$? There's no obvious reason why $x_n$ converges, and the assertion that there is some $x \in A$ such that $y = Tx$ is precisely what we're trying to prove.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it. Since $T$ is injective and $T(X)$ is closed T is bijective and thus invertible (open mapping theorem). Then $||x||=||T^{-1}Tx||\leq ||T^{-1}||\Vert Tx\Vert $. Hence, $\Vert Tx\Vert\geq M\Vert x\Vert $ with $M=\frac{1}{T^{-1}}$. Therefore, $\Vert x_n-x_m\Vert\leq\frac{1}{M}\Vert Tx_n-Tx_m\Vert=\frac{1}{M}\Vert y_n-y_m\Vert.$ Thus, $ x_n $ is Cauchy and converges (because $X$ is Banach). So $x_n\rightarrow x\in A$ and $Tx=y\in T(A)$.

Comment: Looks good! I would have cited the Bounded Inverse Theorem instead, but the rest looks solid.